# '+' doesnt appear in path in Firebase Storage with IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Im storing images in firebase storage with the following code:

```
let smallPhotoProfilRef = currentUserRef.child("small").child("+972501234567.jpg")
let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpg
print("bucket : \(smallPhotoProfilRef.bucket)")
print("fullpath : \(smallPhotoProfilRef.fullPath)")
print("name : \(smallPhotoProfilRef.name)")

let uploadTaskForSmall = smallPhotoProfilRef.putData(imageDataSmall!, metadata: metaData) { metadata, error in
       if (error != nil) {

       } else {
             let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
             print(downloadURL)
       }
}
```

I use the prints to verify my path value and as expected Im getting in the log:

```
bucket : XXX.appspot.com
fullpath : usersPhone/small/+972501234567.jpg
name : +972501234567.jpg
```

But in my firebase storage console , the file is appearing without the '+' sign
[image: Image in my storage console]

Of course its the same result in the image preview:
[image: Image preview in storage console]

NB: the problem seems not to happens in ANDROID

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed this is a bug in the iOS client--looks like our HTTP library doesn't like the plus (it's converting it to a space). We'll investigate and get a bug fix out soon, sorry about this!

Comment: No problem :) , "forgiving" you because of your great work and platform ! Keep us posted when it will be fixed